# Application closes when it's hidden and I close a modal dialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm developing an application which will "run in the tray" much of the time, and displays dialogs to the user (these dialogs are modal)

The problem I've run into is that when the user closes the dialog (using `accept()` or `reject()`) while the main window (the parent of the modal dialog) is hidden the whole application is closed!

There is no problem for modeless dialogs

The workaround that I'm using now is to call `show()` on the parent (the main window) first and only after this close the modal dialog

**Is there another better way to solve or avoid this problem?** Or is the approach I'm already using a good way to deal with this issue?

I'm using PyQt 5.7.1 (same as the Qt version) and am running on Lubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to set the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) property on your `QApplication` object to `False`, As I show below::

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not QSystemTrayIcon.isSystemTrayAvailable():
        QMessageBox.critical(None, "Systray",
                "I couldn't detect any system tray on this system.")
        sys.exit(1)

    QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    window = yourDialog()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```